# Cannot use apt-get install due to missing libfftw3-long3

Tags: apt, software-installation, synaptic

How do I install libfftw3-long3?

I have tried to install it with Synaptic but that does not work due to the missing libfftw3-long3.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally as you probably know packages should be installed by using the Software Center,  command line using `apt-get` or by using Synaptic. However I appreciate if all of these are complaining of a missing file you are in a quandary. There is a final choice:

This file can be manually downloaded by following these links:

1. Trusty Tahr amd64:

   - http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-long3_3.3.3-7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
2. Trusty Tahr i386:

   - http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-long3_3.3.3-7ubuntu3_i386.deb
3. Xenial Xerus amd64

   - http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-long3_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
4. Xenial Xerus i386

   - http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-long3_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_i386.deb

And then installed using the following command line syntax:

```
sudo dpkg -i path_to_filename
```

And hopefully this will be enough to get you up and running :)

**References:**

- [Ubuntu Documentation: dpkg](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dpkg.html)